# Re-flag of question should replace previous flags marking them as disputed

Tags: feature-request, flags, disputed-flags

Since the last changes in flagging I can not flag a post more then once. Previously if the flag I raised became invalid(e.g. if the author edits the post) I flagged the post again to say "my previous flag is not valid", both flags being marked as disputed. I believe this saved the moderators some work.

Now that I can not flag a post more than once it is not possible to remove an invalid flag. I did not like the old system too much, but I don't think the new way is much better. For instance if I accidentally put a wrong flag on a question I can not remove it. I think the best option is to enable a user to flag a post more than once but each flag should mark the previous ones as `disputed`. This will save the moderators some work of looking into invalid flags.

Comment: Having fat-fingered a couple of flags recently, some way to undo a flag may be useful, although I didn't realise my mistakes until looking at my list of flags, by which time it was too late. However, I may also be tempted to cheat if this were available, and remove my flag from a very obvious to-be-closed question from July, to re-flag it so that it gets some attention.

Comment: @PompousQWoodger but this feature will not change your active number of flags, it simply will replace an active flag with another one. It happened to me today that I selected the option `has invalid flags` instead of `is not an answer` and it is really annoying that I can not correct that.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I did a similar thing, twice, recently (although I didn't become aware of it in time for the feature-request to have helped). I'm just saying it could be put to a different use. I have an Active flag which is months old. Nothing I can do with it. It is amongst all the Close Vote Queue stuff. If I could re-flag, I'd be happier (personally), but it would in this case make for more work for others, not less. If feeling obtuse I could do it for all my 17 Active flags. Same again tomorrow. Day after. Until I have none left. Or get banned for a bit. Consider ab-use as well.

Comment: @PompousQWoodger but this will not create more work for others. They will still have a single flag to review it will only be more recent.

Comment: Many of my Active flags are in the CVQ. Presumably something may already have been done by someone, but not by enough people to complete the thing. If I re-flag, the something already done is wasted, and the question gets a new look. If I re-present all my 17 Active flags every day for a week, maybe some will be cleared, but mostly I'll be annoying people with the power to act on the flags. Perhaps I misunderstand how it works?

Comment: Basically I'm saying I think it would be useful, as long as there is no downside.